# Laravel 5.6: Force logout remember me login

Tags: php, session, cookies, laravel-5.6, remember-me

I have a custom login controller in my app, which prevents multiple sessions per user. It logs out the user if they log in from another device/browser:

```
public function authenticated(Request $request, $user) {
  $previous_session = $user->session_id;

  if ($previous_session) {
    session()->getHandler()->destroy($previous_session);
  }

  auth()->user()->session_id = session()->getId();
  auth()->user()->save();

  return redirect(session()->pull('from', $this->redirectTo));
}
```

Regardless of the session driver, this code looks for a `session_id` on `users` table and destroys the session associated with it.

But this doesn't work if the user logged in with remember me checkbox enabled. User stays logged in with previous device/browser. How can I tell laravel to forget this remember me after the second login? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to invalidate or cycle the `remember_token` in the `users` database table.

This happens automatically when you call `Auth::logout()`.

The `remember_token` can also be invalidated manually similiar to how Laravel handles it:

```
protected function cycleRememberToken(AuthenticatableContract $user)
{
    $user->setRememberToken($token = Str::random(60));

    $this->provider->updateRememberToken($user, $token);
}
```

Source: laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php